# Cucumber and Capybara : How to wait for next page to load. After I click on submit button,Test case is failing and not able to find element

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

How to wait for next page to load. After I click on submit button(Basic Registration flow), Test case is failing and not able to find element. I'm quite new to this, first time using cucumber and capybara.

**I have given 10 seconds in default wait time, is there any way to explicitly wait for that element using capybara.**

Error :

```
Scenario: Register with valid credentials                                  # features/Job_seeker_Registration.feature:6
    Given I am on "/register"                                                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:2
Unable to find field "#jobseekerName"
    When I have entered "Seeker1" into the "jobseekerName" field             # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:6
Unable to find field "#jobseekerMobileOrEmail"
    When I have entered "7812125899" into the "jobseekerMobileOrEmail" field # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:6
    Then I wait for 1 seconds                                                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
    When I pick "Driver" from "field-desiredcategory"                        # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:16
Unable to find field "#jobseekerPassword"
    When I have entered "4679" into the "jobseekerPassword" field            # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:6
    And I click on "jobSeekerRegister"                                       # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:11
    Then I wait for 40 seconds                                               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
    Then I should see "verificationButton"                                   # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:25
      expected to find text "verificationButton" in "SEARCH JOBS SEARCH CANDIDATES LOOKING TO HIRE? (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      features/Job_seeker_Registration.feature:15:in `Then I should see "verificationButton"'
    And I click on "Seeker 1"                                                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:11
    And I click on "Edit my Profile"                                         # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:11
    Then I wait for 1 seconds                                                # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
    HTML screenshot: ./screenshot/screenshot.html
    Image screenshot: ./screenshot/screenshot.png

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/Job_seeker_Registration.feature:6 # Scenario: Register with valid credentials

1 scenario (1 failed)
12 steps (1 failed, 3 skipped, 8 passed)
0m55.271s
```

Code:

```
Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |text|
    page.should have_content(text)
end
Then /^I should see title "(.*?)"$/ do |text|
    page.should have_title?(text)
end
Given /^I wait for (\d+) seconds?$/ do |n|
    sleep(n.to_i)
end
```

Comment: Please show the error message and the code that's causing the error.

Comment: And now the corresponding code, please.

Comment: Added, hope you are asking abt this code only.

Comment: It's your question so it's up to you how much information you are providing. But a [mcve] is more likely to have upvotes and helpful answers.

Comment: You need to show the code for web_steps.rb around line 6 and the html this is supposed to be interacting with

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to adjust how you're testing for the presence of the element. If you're doing it correctly, Capybara will wait until the element appears.

For example:

```rb
# this noes not wait until the element exists
first(".active").click
```

but if you use find

```rb
# this this waits until an element with the class "active" is found
find(".active").click
```

Thoughtbot have [a great article](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/write-reliable-asynchronous-integration-tests-with-capybara) giving more examples on this.